# Excel formula to count a number in first column and output in corresponding column in same row?

Tags: excel

Hello guys I was trying to achieve the following in Excel

```
A   B   C   D   E
1   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0
2   0   1   0   0
1   2   0   0   0
2   0   2   0   0
```

So if I enter a number in A column the corresponding column to that number counts how many times the number occurred in A and outputs the same in the same row at the corresponding column. I ve tried `B = COUNTIF(A1:A1000, 1)`but this is useless if you know what I mean. Any ideas on how to achieve the result?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? I don't think I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Jerry its hard to put in english for me. But please see the Matrix and imagine it is an excel sheet.

Comment: Okay, what is in the sheet at first and what are to be calculated? In other words, what's the before, what's the after?

Comment: @Jerry I will entering numbers in A column the B, C, D, E are the counts for that number. If I put a number 1 in say A10 so I want B10  to Count number of 1s from A0 to A10. If I put 2 in say A12 I want C12 to count number of 2s in A0 to A12 and output in C12.

Comment: if your data starts from `A2` cell, than you can write in `B2` something like this: `=COUNTIF(A$2:A2, A2)` and drop it down

Comment: If I understood, in your matrix, the cell B1 should have 1 and B2 should have 0, right?

Comment: @Jerry yes I corrected it B4 will count 2 if count of 1 in A1 upto A4 is 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula in B1 copied down and across

`=IF($A1=COLUMNS($B1:B1),COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,COLUMNS($B1:B1)),0)`

That will give the results you showed

Comment: @Thanks Barry exactly what I wanted.